# execute update query inside db.each

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, sqlite

I am using javascript and sqlite and trying to run an UPDATE query, after AJAX post on success, inside SELECT query.
The SELECT and AJAX post was successfull, but on UPDATE, return error : **Error: SQLITE_BUSY: database is locked**

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('sqlite-database.db');

db.serialize(function(){

        db.each("SELECT id_sales, id_customer, date FROM sales where syncstatus = 0", function(err, row) {

        id_sales = row.id_sales;
        id_customer = row.id_customer;
        date = row.date;

        $.ajax('http://localhost/newserver/sales/sync_sales', {
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: { id_sales_ori: id_sales, id_customer:id_customer, date: date },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {


                var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
                var db = new sqlite3.Database('sqlite-database.db');

            db.run("UPDATE sales set syncstatus = $status WHERE id_sales = $id_sales",{
                $id_sales: id_sales,
                $status: 1,
            },function (err,rows){
                if (err === null){
                console.log("syncstatus update to 1");
                }else{
                console.log(err);
                }
            });

            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    console.log("fail sync");
                    stat[id_sales] = 0;
                }
        });        

    });
});
db.close();
```

please help me how to do the UPDATE query inside of db.each properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because you're opening db second time when it's already in progress or in use.

```
 $.ajax('http://localhost/newserver/sales/sync_sales', {
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data: { id_sales_ori: id_sales, id_customer:id_customer, date: date },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                //..........try removing these two lines............
                var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
                var db = new sqlite3.Database('sqlite-database.db');

            db.run("UPDATE sales set syncstatus = $status WHERE id_sales = $id_sales",{
                $id_sales: id_sales,
                $status: 1,
            },function (err,rows){
                if (err === null){
                console.log("syncstatus update to 1");
                }else{
                console.log(err);
                }
            });

            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    console.log("fail sync");
                    stat[id_sales] = 0;
                }
        });
```